# How to replace Guava's ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet() collector with an alternative, if you're stuck with using Guava 20.0?

Tags: java, guava

I am hitting some Guava dependency issues that would require quite a bit of work to sort out. Due to a third-party library also depending on Guava, (which I unfortunately have to use), I have to downgrade my dependency of Guava from `27.0.1-jre` all the way back to `20.0`. It seems that there are no major side-effects other than the following bit of code now being broken, since the `ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()` was only introduced in Guava `21.0`:

```
ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet();
```

The full code block is:

```
cronJobDefinitions = cronJobsRegistry.get()
                                     .stream()
                                     .map(ThrowingFunction.unchecked(clazz -> clazz.newInstance()
                                                                                   .getCronJobDefinition()))
                                     .collect(ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet());
```

Is there a simple way to replace `ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()` with an alternative in the JDK, maybe? I'm currently using JDK8, (but would be curious to hear, if there are better solutions in newer JDK-s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can collect it as a Set using `Collectors.toSet`. But there are no guarantees on the type of the returned Set. So, you can use `Collectors.collectingAndThen` to convert the above set into a Google Guava `ImmutableSet`.

```
cronJobDefinitions = cronJobsRegistry.get()
    .stream()
    .map(..)
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(), ImmutableSet::copyOf));
```

Comment: Thanks a million! This was a neat and simple workaround that saved me a lot time.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from JDK 9 you can use

```
Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()
```

Here is [Oracle's doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/core/creating-immutable-lists-sets-and-maps.htm#JSCOR-GUID-29B476E6-66E9-4C95-B744-874ECA6FAB51) concerning this.